# How to access objects inside an array of JSON object?

Tags: json, reactjs

I'm trying to access object inside an array of a JSONObject and print its values.

I'm able to print the array as JSONObject using console.log. But i fail to access the values inside the array which are again JSONObject format. Following is my my JSONObject

```
{
    "id": 4,
    "meta": {
        "type": "pagetype",
            "title": "Home"
        }
    },
    "title": "Expose data to frontend",
    "subtitle": "We will be exposing the content to the frontend",
    "content": [
        {
            "type": "full_richtext",
            "value": "<p><b>Bold body</b></p>"
        },
        {
            "type": "button",
            "value": {
                "button_text": "Google",
                "button_url": "https://google.com"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to access the values inside the array "content" and print values for

```
"value" -- Bold body --
"button_text"
"button_url"
```

I have tried it as follows

```
    class App extends React.Component {
       constructor() {
          super();
          this.state = {
             'items': []
          }
       }
       componentDidMount() {
          fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/v2/pages/4/')
             .then(results => results.json())
             .then(results => this.setState({ 'items': results }));
          }

          render() {
             var contents_from_wagtail = this.state.items;
             var streamfield_content_array = contents_from_wagtail.content;
             console.log(streamfield_content_array); //prints array of objects

             return (
                <React.Fragment>
                    <p>{this.state.items.subtitle}</p>
                    <p>{this.state.items.title}</p>
                    /* print the values for 
                      "value" -- Bold body --
                      "button_text"
                      "button_url"
                    */
                </React.Fragment>
             );
         }
      }
 export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

When showing an array of items the `.map` method can be used to create multiple elements:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            'items': {}
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/v2/pages/4/')
            .then(results => results.json())
            .then(results => this.setState({ 'items': results }));
    }

    render() {
        var contents_from_wagtail = this.state.items;
        var streamfield_content_array = contents_from_wagtail.content || [];
        console.log(streamfield_content_array); //prints array of objects

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <p>{this.state.items.subtitle}</p>
                <p>{this.state.items.title}</p>
                {streamfield_content_array.map((item, index) => {
                    return <div key={index}>type: {item.type} <p>{item.value}</p></div>
                })}
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

More `.map` examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: it says 'streamfield_content_array' is undefined.

Comment: thanks for the effort but still it says 'Objects are not valid as React Child'. I think that is because here we are using .map function on objects other than array ..

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of `.map()` and `.filter()` to iterate over the items within the content array. It looks like you only want to display items that have a `type` of `button`. So try something like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
   constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
         'items': []
      }
   }
   componentDidMount() {
      fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/v2/pages/4/')
         .then(results => results.json())
         .then(results => this.setState({ 'items': results }));
      }

      render() {
         var contents_from_wagtail = this.state.items;
         var streamfield_content_array = contents_from_wagtail.content;
         var buttonContent = this.state.items ? this.state.items.content.filter((item) => item.type == "button") : null

         return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <p>{this.state.items.subtitle}</p>
                <p>{this.state.items.title}</p>
                 { buttonContent && buttonContent.map(item => (
                    <div>
                       <p>{item.button_text}</p>
                       <p>{item.button_url}</p>
                    </div>
                 ))}
            </React.Fragment>
         );
     }
  }
 export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

To access it within the render you have to access it conditional because it is not set for the first render until the fetch call is Executed

That is why you have to provide some fallback until the array is loaded.just check if the item is undefined and return null for example.

Only if the array is filled render the desires output and it should be fine. 
Hope this helps. Happy coding.